# Custom sorting string with numbers in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

My data set looks like this.

[image: screenshot of my dataset]

I want to sort based on first column (first it should sort based on numerical value followed by alphabetical order), so that it would look like this. How can I do this without VBA code but with custom sorting formula.

[image: desired sorting pattern]

*Ignore the unsorted value in 2nd column*

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Excel installed currently, but I remember there's a formula to get everything but the first character. I think something like `=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)`. You can then put that in a separate column that you sort on, and hide that column if you don't want to see it.

Comment: could the person down voting this answer please explain to me what's wrong with it, so I can learn from that?

Comment: As you are not sure it will work, also you do not put full answer, so you should not put it as answer. You can simply write it as comment.

Comment: I am pretty sure it will work, I've done this in the past. Always thought a comment is more for asking explanation etc. I believe this will help the person asking the question to solve their problem. I only mentioned that I don't have Excel installed, so that they don't paste it in blindly, but the exact syntax will be autocompleted.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following `ARRAY` formula to `D2` cell.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(SMALL(CODE($A$2:$A$11)*10^RIGHT($A$2:$A$11,1),ROWS($A$2:$A2)),CODE($A$2:$A$11)*10^RIGHT($A$2:$A$11,1),0))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

***Note:*** Again, you must press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after entering formula.